# Design considerations while choosing type of spring controller

Tags: angularjs, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

In a typically web application, where my back end services and client (AngularJS) are deployed in different containers, how should i chose which controller to code in Spring Boot.

Should i use

1. @Controller with @ResponseBody or
2. use @RestController or
3. use spring-boot-starter-jersey?

What are the pros and cons for each design choice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[@RestController](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RestController.html) is just a replacement for @Controller and @ResponseBody, hence there's no point in using them when the first option is more expressive and concise.

The main difference between other options is that spring-boot-starter-jersey by default uses JAX-RS annotations while @RestController is part of Spring. You can easily create desired REST services for your AngularJS application with both solutions.

Spring REST services are said to be not compliant with the JAX-RS language specification but it is up to you to decide whether it's important for you or not. JAX-RS isn't required to design a RESTful architecture.

In addition, Jersey is just a JAX-RS implementation so it only allows you building REST endpoints while Spring provides you with more features, like for instance, creating dynamic views where a simple JSON output is not enough.

So all in all, it's up to you to decide what really fits your needs.

Comment: Thanks Daniel for the detailed answer. The backend services return JSON. There are no views associated with it. If the consumer of these services is mobile app or PHP or Drupal application in addition to AngularJS web app, would @RESTController still suffice? In such instances, should I go for a truly JAX-RS implementation?

Comment: To be honest, it doesn't really matter which one you choose in this case as both solutions will work perfectly fine. Ask yourself whether you prefer prospective extensibility provided by Spring or being compliant to JAX-RS which actually gives you nothing beside possibility to change its implementation in the foreseeable future. This question's a reason for marking your question as opinion-based.

Comment: You walcome. If this satisfy your need, please, be so kind to accept and/or upvote the answer.